# Angularjs read value of object in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
"node" : {
    "title": "Event hold tomorow",
    "field_mobile_image" : " {'src' : 'http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/image_default_banner.jpg','alt' : ''}"
  }
}, "node" : {
    "title": "Event hold tomorow",
    "field_mobile_image" : " {'src' : 'http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/image_default_banner.jpg','alt' : ''}"
  }
}
```

I have some JSON data that looks like the above from an API I am trying to display this result in a loop with angujarjs i can't figure out how to read the value of 'src' i keep getting an undefined
my template looks like this

```
<a class="list card" ng-repeat="newsitem in news" style="display:block;text-decoration:none;" ui-sref="menu.newsDetail()" id="news-card22">
<img ng-src="{{newsitem.node.field_mobile_image.src}}">
  <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>{{newsitem.node.title}}</ion-item>
```

the controller looks like this

```
 function($scope, $stateParams, getPageInfo) {
    getPageInfo.news().then(function(res) {
        $scope.news = res;
    });
```

The service looks like

```
.service('getPageInfo', ['$http', function($http) {
    news: function() {
      let api_url = "http://example.com/";
        endpoint = "api/news";
        return $http.get(api_url + endpoint).then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.data.data[0].node.field_mobile_image.src); //undefined 
            return resp.data.data
        });
    }
return ret;
```

}]);

Comment: show the `news` array

Comment: use `ng-src` instead of `src` more details is here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-src.asp

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka the news array is the JSON object it the first code I posted ng-src is no the issue when i console.log i get an emtpy value for image

Comment: I think the JSON format you are getting might wrong. it shoud be like this
{"src" : "http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/image_default_banner.jpg","alt" : ''}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because the value of the `field_mobile_image` is actually a JSON string, so it does not have a property of `src`. You’ll need to fix up your whole object and run `JSON.parse()` on that property in addition to whatever steps you took to get access to the entire JSON structure. Showing the entire news array would be helpful, if you’re not sure how to write a function to do that.

Edit: Also, you will need to use `ng-src`, as the commenters recommended.

Moar edit: To tease this out, consider that the property in question is actually wrapped in double quotes, so it is not an object, it is a string. Looking at the list of properties and methods on (any) string, you will not find `src`. Here’s some [reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) for that.

To make this string an object, the parse function will actually iterate through the characters of the string and identify what the object should look like and return that to you. Here’s an example of how you might handle that for a single item:

```
function fixData (data) {
  data.field_mobile_image = JSON.parse(data.field_mobile_image)
  return data
}
```

Comment: thanks for you response i tried this and it throws a SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: There must be a rogue single quote character in your data. Where are you getting your data from? Make sure you’re not trying to run `JSON.parse()` on something that is _not_ JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON DATA

```
$scope.news = {
node : {
  title : "Event hold tomorow",
  field_mobile_image : {
      src : "http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/image_default_banner.jpg",
      alt : ''
  }
}}
```

Html template

```
<a class="list card" ng-repeat="newsitem in news" style="display:block;text- 
 decoration:none;" ui-sref="menu.newsDetail()" id="news-card22">
  <img ng-src="{{newsitem.field_mobile_image.src}}">
   <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>{{newsitem.title}}</ion-item>
```